# Embedding URI as id/name for GUI elements in react.JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to build a front end by passing URI as name/id properties to the GUI components in react.js. Later i want to map the  URI keys to some values. As the web page is requested, it has to get the mapped value.

```
<input type="text" name="someURI" value="mapedURI.value">
```

Is this possible? else is there any other way to send the values to GUI elemnts after the page is rendered completely. But still after rendering it has to reflect values.

Comment: What are you referencing as a URI? What would `"mapedURI.value"` reference?

Comment: @guest271314 URI will be some unique generated by URI generator(say http://abc.xyz/person#firstName). and mappedURI.values are the one which i do some operation on back end and bind some value to that particular URI which has to reflected on the front end.

Comment: `{"abc.xyz/person#firstName":"value"}`?

Comment: @guest271314 yes!

Comment: You could probably use an array of objects if more than one `<input>` element is rendered `[{"abc.xyz/person#firstName":"value"}]`

Comment: @guest271314 i have the JSON object of values which are supposed to be reflected on the GUI. My concern is how to trigger the event of update after complete render of the page, and howto pass this JSON object over there?

Comment: You can iterate the elements and set the `.name` and `.value` properties of the elements to the property, value pairs of the JavaScript object at the same index of the current element within the iteration

Answer (score 0):

I totally forgot about the this.setState() in componentDidMount() and getting the values from backend with rest POST call.